# Consume multiple topics at the same time from single consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

There are multiple topics and these topics have no key value relation. The first payload of topic1 (has no key) example as it follows:

```json
{ "bookList": [{"bookId": "1"}, {"bookId": "2"} ],"magazineList": [{"magazineId": "1"}, {"magazineId": "2"} ]
```

the second payload of topic2 (has a random integer key value) is:

```json
{ "libraryId": "1", "cityId": "1" }
```

Let's assume these payloads consume at the same t time and these topics in the same consumer group. What I am trying to do is to consume these topic1 and topic2 at the same time (maybe using stream) and aggregate/process these payloads. What should I do?

Some source say the topics should have the same key to process different topics but I am new to Kafka and couldn't find my answer. Is the below approach correct?

```java
KafkaConsumer<String,String> Consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String,String>(properties);
       Consumer.subscribe("topic1");
       Consumer.subscribe("topic2");

        
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<Integer,String> records=Consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));  
                 for(ConsumerRecord<String,String> record: records){  
            System.out.println(record);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> consume these topic1 and topic2 at the same time

Use a regex pattern

```
Consumer.subscribe("topic[12]");
```

> aggregate/process these payloads. What should I do?

Don't use the consumer API for this. Use Kafka Streams.

> Some source say the topics should have the same key

To *join* the data, yes. Not to consume both, in parallel.

Comment: I will join data with KStream and KTable for my logic. Thank you for your Kafka Stream suggestion. By the way, the actual topic names are different than topic1 and topic2 but I was no sure if I can regex too. Cool!